How to make CoreData Manager with multi accounts?
My iOS app can change account.
SQLite file is saved to [account]_dbfile.sqlite.
If I logged in ABC named account, call CoreDataManager.shared.setup("ABC") and fetch, save blahblah...
Then, if I change Account DEF named, call CoreDataManager.shared.resetCoreDataObjects() -> CoreDataManager.shared.setup("DEF") and fetch, save blahblah...
This is my code.
I don't know this is correct code.
class CoreDataManager: NSObject {
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    private(set) var isLoggedin: Bool = false
    
    private lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestAppModel")
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in }
        return container
    }()
    
    private var moc: NSManagedObjectContext {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            return persistentContainer.viewContext
        } else {
            return privateContext
        }
    }
    
    private lazy var privateContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let privateManagedContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateManagedContext.parent = persistentContainer.viewContext
        return privateManagedContext
    }()
    
    func setup(_ userId: String) -> Bool {
        moc.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
        
        guard let path = FileManager.databasePath(userId: userId) else {        // ex) "~/[userId]_dbfile.sqlite"
            isLoggedin = false
            return isLoggedin
        }
        
        for persistentStore in persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores {
            if persistentStore.url?.lastPathComponent == path.lastDepthName() {
                isLoggedin = true
                print("Already added PersistentStore = \(String(describing: persistentStore.url?.relativePath))")
                
                return true
            }
        }
        
        let options: [String: Any] = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
                                            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true,
                                                NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey: FileProtectionType.complete]
        
        do {
            _ = try persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(type: .sqlite, at: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: options)
        } catch {
            isLoggedin = false
            return isLoggedin
        }
        
        isLoggedin = true
        return isLoggedin
    }
    
    func resetCoreDataObjects() {
        moc.performAndWait {
            for store in persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores {
                try? persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.remove(store)
            }
        }
    }
}


Do you want to remove all data for account ABC when the user switches to DEF or would they expect to be able to switch back to ABC and have their previous data available?

@Paulw11 I don't want to delete previous data file when switch other accounts. The previous DB data is need to persist. After switch back to ABC like ABC -> DEF -> ABC, I want to use previous ABC db file.
